# os.listdir not working: script only grabs file name and not data wtihin

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I am currently working on a script to send various files to an s3 bucket. The files successfully send to the bucket with no issue, but when I open the files they do not show any data. These files seemed to have only transferred the actual files "names" (.i.e. file1.csv) as a "string", but do not the actual .csv containing any data within.

An example below is a directory containing files that I sent to my s3:

/home/user/Desktop/

file1.csv
file2.csv
file3.csv
file4.csv

How can I update my code to send

```
import fnmatch
import os
import glob
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'some_key'
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = 'some_key'
BUCKET_NAME = 'isome_bucket'


s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

for file in os.listdir('/home/user/Desktop/'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.csv'):

    key = "folder_1/" + file
    s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=key, Body=file)


print("Complete")
```

Comment: You also need to read the the **csv** file before putting it to s3

Comment: Put your body as `fileb://filepath/filename`.

Comment: [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) only returns a list of filenames. you need to acces the files you want to send first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply passing the name of your file to s3. I think the  [upload_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file) API will serve you better here instead of put_object. You can simply pass in the full path for upload_file and it will work instead of you having to open the file and reading the content yourself. Replace your put_object method with this and it should work.

```
s3.upload_file('/home/user/Desktop/'+file, BUCKET_NAME, key)
```